# Append multiple styled radio button

Tags: jquery, css

This radio input is appended from PHP through an AJAX call made in jQuery. Every time the user clicks a button one radio is appended from the PHP code. The radio inputs works perfectly when they are not styled. When I try using this style they stop switching. I guess the problem is the `div` but I am not sure.

```
.h_tick {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    width: -webkit-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    width: -moz-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
}    
.tc {
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
}    
label.tick {
    color: ;
    text-align: center;
}    
input.tick {
    display: none;
    float: left;
}    
input.tick[type=radio] + label.tick div.tc {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: ;
    border-radius: 3px;
}    
input.tick[type="radio"]:checked + label.tick div.tc:after {
    content: '✔';
    color: #09ad7e;
}
```

```
<div class="h_tick">
    <input class="tick" type="radio" id="tk" value=""/>
    <label class="tick" for="tk">
        <div class="tc" style=""></div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="h_tick">
    <input class="tick" type="radio" id="tk" value=""/>
    <label class="tick" for="tk">
        <div class="tc" style=""></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is by design. Radio inputs can only be deselected when another radio of the same name is selected in its place. If you want to turn a radio on/off, use a checkbox instead.

Note that if you are using multiple radio inputs yet only want to allow one of them to be selected (as is their purpose), then you need to give them all the same name and remove the `id` attribute to prevent duplicates.

Here's a working example:

```css
.h_tick {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    width: -webkit-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    width: -moz-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
}    
.tc {
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
}    
label.tick {
    text-align: center;
}    
input.tick {
    display: none;
    float: left;
}    
label.tick div.tc {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}    
input.tick[type="radio"]:checked + div.tc:after {
    content: '✔';
    color: #09ad7e;
}
```

```html
<div class="h_tick">
    <label class="tick">
        <input class="tick" type="radio" value="" name="foo" />
        <div class="tc"></div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="h_tick">
    <label class="tick">
        <input class="tick" type="radio" value="" name="foo" />
        <div class="tc"></div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="h_tick">
    <label class="tick">
        <input class="tick" type="radio" value="" name="foo" />
        <div class="tc"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what's your issue:

- in your current example, there is only one radio button, so it gets no sense alone: an *alone* unchecked radio button will become checked when clicked, then will remain checked when clicking again
- as soon as we put a second one, assumed the important condition we give it the same `name`, all works fine

Look at this snippet illustrating the above.

```css
.h_tick {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
  width: -webkit-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
  width: -moz-calc(14.28% - 1.85px);
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}
.tc {
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
}
label.tick {
  color:;
  text-align: center;
}
input.tick {
 /* display: none;*/
  float: left;

}
input.tick[type=radio] + label.tick div.tc {
  color: #fff;
  background-color:;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input.tick[type="radio"]:checked + label.tick div.tc:after{  
  content: '✔';
  color: #09ad7e;
}
```

```html
<div class="h_tick">
  <input class="tick" type="radio" id="tk1" name="tk" value=""/>
  <label class="tick" for="tk">
    <div class="tc" style="">
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="h_tick">
  <input class="tick" type="radio" id="tk2" name="tk" value=""/>
  <label class="tick" for="tk">
    <div class="tc" style="">
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Note that not only there is a common `name` for both radio buttons, but also and at the opposite they must have different `id`s.

Comment: You are right I missed the second radio in the example. Thanks for helping cFreed.